# How to render a partial only when a user clicks the corresponding link?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, ruby-on-rails-5

So currently I have a button dropdown using bootstrap and depending on which item from the dropdown is selected javascript is used to either show or hide partials. These partials are actually shown within a bootstrap modal window.

The issue is that the javascript is "showing" one partial at a time to the user based on what button dropdown was selected but ALL partials are being rendered within the modal, they are just hidden from view.

I was thinking it would be better performance wise to not have all the partials rendered within the modal and hide them, but to actually just call them only at the time when a user selects one from the dropdown.

I'm not sure how to accomplish calling a partial from a button dropdown.  Maybe I just need a route for my partial that I call using link_to and cut out all the javascript?  something like `<li><%= link_to "test", my_partial_path(@user) %></li>`

here's my button dropdown and javascript

```
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">   
        <!-- Button dropdown -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            Add <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul id="select_id" class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
            <li id="cert0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Certification</a></li>
            <li id="course0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Course</a></li>
            <li id="award0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Award or Honor</a></li>
            <li id="language0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Language</a></li>
            <li id="patent0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Patent</a></li>
            <li id="publication0" class="dropdown-item"><a href="#achievementModal0" data-toggle="modal">Publication</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>          
      </div><!-- ./col-xs-6 -->


   <!-- renders different partials within the modal based off user selection -->
   <script>
      $('li.dropdown-item').click(function ()
      {
        //alert(this.id);

         if (this.id == "cert0") 
          $("div#cert").show(); 
         else
          $("div#cert").hide(); 

         if (this.id == "course0") 
          $("div#course").show(); 
         else
          $("div#course").hide();      

         if (this.id == "award0") 
          $("div#award").show(); 
         else
          $("div#award").hide(); 

         if (this.id == "language0") 
          $("div#language").show(); 
         else
          $("div#language").hide();  

         if (this.id == "patent0") 
          $("div#patent").show(); 
         else
          $("div#patent").hide();  

         if (this.id == "publication0") 
          $("div#publication").show(); 
         else
          $("div#publication").hide();        

      });
  </script>
```

here's the modal body where all partials are rendered but only one is shown at a time and the rest are hidden.

```
  <div class="modal-body">

    <!-- a partial is shown based on the user dropdown selection, other partials hidden -->    
    <div id="award">
      <%= render partial: "awards/new_award_modal" %>
    </div>
    <div id="cert">
      <%= render partial: "certifications/new_certification_modal" %>
    </div>
    <div id="course">
      <%= render partial: "courses/new_course_modal" %>
    </div>        
    <div id="language">
      <%= render partial: "languages/new_language_modal" %>
    </div>  
    <div id="patent">
      <%= render partial: "patents/new_patent_modal" %>
    </div>            
    <div id="publication">
      <%= render partial: "publications/new_publication_modal" %>
    </div>            


  </div><!-- modal body -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two alternatives to the task that I can think:

1. Render all partials and show when a user clicks the appropriate link.
2. When a user clicks a link, create an ajax request which requests the partial body from the server and renders it.

You are already implementing the first one. However, which approach is better for performance depends on the usage. If you expect the user to click only a few of the links in a session, then use the ajax approach.

If you expect the user to click almost all the sections or revisit some sections multiple times, then your current approach will be better. This is because, with the ajax approach, you will have to request the server for the partial everytime a user clicks a link. You can, however, optimize the approach by caching the body locally (if you do not expect it to change with every request).

The ajax approach uses remote links. When a user clicks on a link, an ajax request is made. The server returns a piece of javascript code as response which runs on the browser to render the partial. Here is an example. Suppose your modal dialog has a section to create a new award and the modal to be rendered is `awards/new_award_modal`

```
<%= link_to "New Award", controller: "awards", action: :new, :remote => true %>
```

In the awards controller

```
def new
 @new_award = Award.new
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

First give an id to the modal container:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="my-modal">
</div>
```

Create a views/awards/new.js.erb. Here, you will write the javascript code to render the partial

```
#views/awards/new.js.erb
$("#my-modal").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'awards/new_award_modal', locals: { award: @new_award } ) %>");
```

Comment: Can you please share the reason for downvoting?